# Error in Focus on textbox using asp.net web appln

Tags: asp.net, ajax

In the below code i have a textbox when focus comes to my textbox it should call serverside codebehind file using ajax but in my case i can get success alert but it is not moving to serverside and return the value pls help me to fix the issue.
code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#<%=txtField.ClientID%>").bind("focus", function () {
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<%=Request.FilePath%>/txtField_GotFocus",
                  data: "{foo:'whatever'}",
                  success: function (msg) {
                      alert(msg); //awesome, it works!
                  },
                  error: function (xhr) {
                  }
              });
          });
      });
</script>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static"  OnTextChanged="txtField_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

codebehind

```
public static string txtField_GotFocus()
        {
            string foo = HttpContext.Current.Request["foo"];
            //code...
            return "awesome, it works!";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You function should look like the following

```
[WebMethod]
public static string txtField_GotFocus()
{
        string foo = HttpContext.Current.Request["foo"];
        //code...
        return "awesome, it works!";
 }
```

Here is a sample link

1. http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: it throws error the type or namespace" webmethodAttribute" could not be found(are u missing a using directive or an assembly reference) when i paste this code

Comment: use `System.Web.Services.dll` in your project.

Comment: add reference of `System.Web.Services`

Comment: Can u tell me how to use  System.Web.Services.dll in my project.Is it a namespace